# need auto increment select query without sequence in oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Kindly help,my question is in attached screenshot.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of questions, or any other text

Answer (score 1):

Given your table and sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE x ( y ) AS
SELECT 10 * LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

You can update the column to add 1 five times:

```sql
UPDATE x
SET y = y + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1;
```

*(You could simplify it by just adding 5.)*

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM x;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> |  Y |
> | -: |
> | 15 |
> | 25 |
> | 35 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=17bd280debcb89414f21600e0ed8faf4)*